# selenium-python cannot locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe

I need to enter credentials on [garmin connect website](https://connect.garmin.com/signin). I use python 3.10 and chrome=108.0.5359.94.

The username element code:

```
<input class="login_email" name="username" id="username" value="" type="email" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-required="true">
```

And I tried the following:

```py
browser.maximize_window()
browser.implicitly_wait(3)

browser.find_element(By.ID, "username")
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'input#username.login_email')
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'login_email')
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/input')
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]')
```

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I searched some info and some say it could be due to shadow dom. But I think it's not my case as I cannot see `shadow-smth` in html structure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login form is inside an iframe. So, to access elements inside it you first need to switch into that iframe.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://connect.garmin.com/signin/"

driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username"))).send_keys("my_name")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys("my_password")
```

The result is

[image]

When finished working inside the iframe don't forget to switch to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```